# jTable.setModel() doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I've created an internal frame that primarily holds a jlist and a jtable.

What I've to do is when the user selects a party or a group of parties in jList, the table should include a column with the selected party name and add it to jTable.[Default jTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pu3C.jpg)

What I have implemented will store the initial tableModel in an object, and every time the user makes changes in jList selection, it will first change the table model to the stored object and then will make changes according to the new selection.[Table After First Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InEf6.jpg)

The problem is that the defined jTable1.setModel() method doesn't work. [Errorunous table after Second Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQSLv.jpg)

PS : Unused Code is Removed. The Problem Contains only the piece of code causing errors. Complete File can be seen at : [Here](http://technfact.in/downloads/DispatchPlanningSelfContained.java)

```
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class DispatchPlanningSelfContained extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    DefaultTableModel defaultdtm;
    public DispatchPlanningSelfContained() {
        initComponents();
        defaultdtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        jList1.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                    //I use either of below method each time
                    jTable1.setModel((TableModel)defaultdtm);// This Doesn't set the tablemodel to default one (I expect this to set the table as Image 1)
                    jTable1.setModel(defaultdtm);// This too Doesn't set the tablemodel to default one

                    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

                    int selection[] = jList1.getSelectedIndices();
                    System.out.println("Selection Length = " + selection.length);
                    for(int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){
                        dtm.addColumn(jList1.getModel().getElementAt(selection[i]));
                            System.out.println("selection [" + i + "] = " + jList1.getModel().getElementAt(selection[i]));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel4.setText("Pending Party Names");

        jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Party 1", "Party 2", "Party 3", "Party 4", "Party 5", "Party 6", "Party 7", "Party 8", "Party 9" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jList1);

        jLabel5.setText("Planning Results:");

        jTable1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Code", "Description", "Rulling", "Page", "MRP", "QPC", "Total Order", "Stock", "Shortage"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 967, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(268, 268, 268)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                                .addComponent(jLabel5))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 531, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 52, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addContainerGap()))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 585, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addGap(96, 96, 96)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DispatchPlanningSelfContained().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts here, with the assumptions underlying it:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
```

The code seems to be treating `dtm` as a ***copy*** of the initial table model, whereas it now simply refers to it.

The easiest fix is to initialize the table model with the raw data each time it's changed:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class DispatchPlanningSelfContained extends JFrame {

    Object[][] data = new Object[][]{};
    String[] titles = {
        "Code", "Description", "Rulling", "Page", 
        "MRP", "QPC", "Total Order", "Stock", "Shortage"
    };

    public DispatchPlanningSelfContained() {
        initComponents();
        jList1.addListSelectionListener((ListSelectionEvent e) -> {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, titles);

                int selection[] = jList1.getSelectedIndices();
                System.out.println("Selection Length = " + selection.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                    dtm.addColumn(jList1.getModel().getElementAt(selection[i]));
                    System.out.println("selection [" + i + "] = " + 
                            jList1.getModel().getElementAt(selection[i]));
                }
                jTable1.setModel(dtm);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel4 = new JLabel();
        jScrollPane3 = new JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new JList<>();
        jLabel5 = new JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel4.setText("Pending Party Names");

        jList1.setModel(new AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = {
                "Party 1", "Party 2", "Party 3", "Party 4", 
                "Party 5", "Party 6", "Party 7", "Party 8", "Party 9"
            };

            @Override
            public int getSize() {
                return strings.length;
            }

            @Override
            public String getElementAt(int i) {
                return strings[i];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jList1);

        jLabel5.setText("Planning Results:");

        jTable1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, titles));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 967, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addGap(268, 268, 268)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel4))
                                                        .addComponent(jLabel5))
                                                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 531, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 52, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                                .addContainerGap()))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 585, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                                .addGap(96, 96, 96)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel5))
                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addContainerGap()))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new DispatchPlanningSelfContained().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private JLabel jLabel4;
    private JLabel jLabel5;
    private JList<String> jList1;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Comment: That was the alternative method I've already used, But why did setModel() method did not work properly?

Comment: *"But why did setModel() method did not work properly?"* What is it you do not understand about.. *"The code seems to be treating `dtm` as a **copy** of the initial table model, whereas it now simply refers to it."*? If that does not explain it for you, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: But I've already stored the initial table model in `defaultdtm`.
Whereas when I use this in setModel(), the initial table model does not seem to be applied.

Comment: It IS applied. Try iterating the elements (or at least checking the number of elements) before applying the original table model. It will, contrary to your current understanding, keep increasing.

Comment: Column count goes 0 after applying `defaultdtm`